# escape double quotes in param file to batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have the following batch script:

Copied it from internet. Need help to modify the script per my requirement.

```
@ECHO OFF
IF "%~1"=="" GOTO :EOF
SET "filename=%~1"
SET fcount=0
SET linenum=0
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-30 delims=|" %%a IN ("%filename%") DO ^
CALL :process "%%a" "%%b" "%%c" "%%d" "%%e" "%%f" "%%g" "%%h" "%%i" "%%j" "%%k" "%%l" "%%m" "%%n" "%%o" "%%p" "%%q" "%%r" "%%s" "%%t" "%%u" "%%v" "%%w" "%%x" "%%y" "%%z" "%%?" "%%_" "%%@" "%%\"
GOTO :EOF

:trim
SET "tmp=%~1"
:trimlead
IF NOT "%tmp:~0,1%"==" " GOTO :EOF
SET "tmp=%tmp:~1%"
GOTO trimlead

:process
SET /A linenum+=1
IF "%linenum%"=="1" GOTO picknames

SET ind=0
:display
IF "%fcount%"=="%ind%" (ECHO.&GOTO :EOF)
SET /A ind+=1
CALL :trim %1
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO !tmp!
ENDLOCAL
SHIFT
GOTO display

:picknames
IF %1=="" GOTO :EOF
CALL :trim %1
SET /a fcount+=1
echo %tmp%
SET "f%fcount%=%tmp%"
SHIFT
GOTO picknames
```

I have the following feed file that I supply as parameter to the batch script above.

```
aa"aaaaa|bbbbbbbb|cccccc
ddddddd|eeeeeeee|ffffff
ggggggg|hhhhhhhh|iiiiii
jjjjjjj|kkkkkkkk|llllll
mmmmmmm|nnnnnnnn|oooooo
```

Notice that the feed file has double quotes. This breaks the script when I try to run the batch script. plz help. Please help in handling other special characters also.

Also, the script above treats the first line differently from other lines. I want it to treat the first line also as any other line. plz help

Comment: As soon as I remove IF '"%linenum%"=="1" GOTO picknames', there is no output from the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This'll do what you expect I think.  It's a batch + Jscript hybrid script.  JScript's reading of stdin and echoing to stdout are a lot more tolerant of special characters than pure batch.  Save it with a `.bat` extension and run it via any of the following methods:

> `parser.bat feedfile.txt`
>
> `parser.bat < feedfile.txt`
>
> `type feedfile.txt | parser.bat`
>
> `feedgenerator.exe | parser.bat`
>
> `parser.bat` *(then paste content into the console.  Hit* <kbd>Enter</kbd> *on a blank line to stop.)*

Here's the script.

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /*

:: batch portion

@ECHO OFF
setlocal

if exist "%~1" (
    cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" < "%~1"
) else (
    cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0"
)

exit /b

:: JScript portion */

while (!WSH.StdIn.AtEndOfLine) {
    var line=WSH.StdIn.ReadLine();
    WSH.Echo(line.split('|').join('\r\n'));
    WSH.Echo();
}
```

Example output:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>test.bat < test.txt
aa"aaaaa
bbbbbbbb
cccccc

ddddddd
eeeeeeee
ffffff

ggggggg
hhhhhhhh
iiiiii

jjjjjjj
kkkkkkkk
llllll

mmmmmmm
nnnnnnnn
oooooo
```

It seems to work just as well with percents, ampersands, carats, and whatever else I could think to throw in.

Comment: Thanks rojo it worked as expected... I guess it is able to handle all the special characters. thanks again.

Comment: In continuation to the above I need to invoke a .vbs file. The file downloads other files from specified files.

Comment: @user646108 - Sorry, but I have no clue what you are asking, or even *if* you are asking.  I guess you are, but your comment is so vague it's hard to tell.

Comment: Hi rojo, since there is lesser space for comment, I created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151876/invoke-vbs-from-batch-script