# invoke .vbs from batch script

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, jscript

In continuation to the script provided by rojo at [escape double quotes in param file to batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970104/escape-double-quotes-in-param-file-to-batch-script), after I have parsed the initial data file, I need to invoke a .vbs script from the batch. The  .vbs script needs to be supplied with 2 of the tokens generated by parsing the initial data file. One of the token is a URL to a file on a server and another is the path on local disk. The .vbs script downloads the specified file specified by token one to local path specified by token two.
What I want to do is to invoke the .vbs script in the script above and pass the tokens as parameters to it.
myvbscript.vbs /FileURL:"https://abc.com/a.pdf" /HDLocation:"C:\a.pdf"

Here is the .bat file i have.

```
    @if(@a==@b) @end
/* :: batch portion
@ECHO OFF
setlocal if exist "%~1"
 ( cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" < "%~1" )
 else ( cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" )
 exit /b 
:: JScript portion */ 
while (!WSH.StdIn.AtEndOfLine) {
 var line=WSH.StdIn.ReadLine();
 var st_token = line.split('\t');
 var FileUR="abc.com/a.pdf";
 var HDLocation="C:\a.pdf"; 
WSH.Echo(req_id); 
WSH.Echo(att_tokens[i]);
 <<INVOKE VBSCRIPT WITH PARAMETERS>>
```

I need to invoke vbscript in place of `<<INVOKE VBSCRIPT WITH PARAMETERS>>` Please help}

Please help me to invoke the .vbs script in the script above with passing tokens as parameters.

The .vbs script is as follows:

```
'Set your settings

Set colNamedArguments = WScript.Arguments.Named

strFileURL = colNamedArguments.Item("FileURL")
strHDLocation = colNamedArguments.Item("HDLocation")

' Fetch the file

Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
objXMLHTTP.send()

If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
  Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  objADOStream.Open
  objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

  objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
  objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start

  Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation
  Set objFSO = Nothing

  objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
  objADOStream.Close
  Set objADOStream = Nothing
End if

Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
```

Comment: The code worked just fine for me, although you could drop the `start "" cmd /c` and just run `cscript` directly. How exactly is it "not working" for you? Do you get an error? What is the value of `objXMLHTTP.Status`?

Comment: The code I updated below should get you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your file use:

For .BAT calling .VBS

```
cscript //nologo [FILE.vbs] argsX argsY
```

For .JS calling .VBS

```
 wsShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
 wsShell.run ("[FILE.VBS] argsX argsY");
```

You will need to read the two parameters into your .vbs and to do that you can use:

```
Set args = WScript.Arguments
argsX = args.Item(0)
argsY = args.Item(1)
```

*Your code has this but I thought I would make a note of how this is being done for anyone else looking for a similar solution.*

Now you can use the arguments/parameters as you would variables in your code.

The .BAT example was tested using testB.bat and within is was the following lines of code.

```
@ECHO OFF
cscript //nologo testv.vbs Hey There
```

The .JS example was tested using test.js and within it was the following lines of code.

```
wsShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
wsShell.run ("testV.VBS Hey There");
```

The code lines in testV.vbs are the following.

```
Set args = WScript.Arguments
firstArg = args.Item(0)
secondArg = args.Item(1)
MsgBox(firstArg)
MsgBox(secondArg)
```

All files are stored in the same directory. Double clicking the test.js or the testB.bat file creates two message boxes. The first says "Hey" and the second says "There".

Comment: Hi, I invoked the code you provied above in Jscript. However, I get this error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'cscript' is undefined. I need to invoke the vbscript in the JScript part as I have the tokens in the Jscript.

Comment: Running batch files (or accessing anything on a user's local computer) is typically blocked/forbidden by browsers. Its a HUGE security risk.

Comment: Javascript\Jscript are browser based (mostly) scripting languages. The "pushd/start" script listed in your question are intended to be run from a command prompt, not in a browser.

Comment: @AxGryndr -1 because you merely replaced named arguments (which are the better choice from a user interface PoV) with unnamed arguments.

Comment: OK because you stated Batch file which is .BAT not .JS - a JScript is different than a Batch file. I believe to resolve the issue you are having you need to change cscript to wscript.

Comment: @Ansgar I used general variable terms not names so someone can understand what the pieces mean. This creates a more general use code that should be modified for your exact purpose. I agree that a programmer should use specific variable names that are meaningful in their code to ensure the while debugging they understand what is happening.

Comment: @AxGryndr Don't go fixing code that isn't broken in the first place. His argument handling is working just fine, and there's no reason for generalizing it.

Comment: @Ansgar you just seem to have a problem. I specified that I added that so someone looking for the solution with a similiar problem understands what is going on. i did not add it to "fix" his code.

Comment: Please help me, heres my batch script '@ if (@ a==@ b) @ end /*

:: batch portion

@ECHO OFF
setlocal

if exist "%~1" (
    cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" < "%~1"
) else (
    cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0"
)

exit /b

:: JScript portion */

while (!WSH.StdIn.AtEndOfLine) {
    var line=WSH.StdIn.ReadLine();
 var st_token = line.split('\t');
 var FileUR="http://abc.com/a.pdf";
 var HDLocation="C:\a.pdf";
 WSH.Echo(req_id);
  WSH.Echo(att_tokens[i]);
  <<INVOKE VBSCRIPT WITH PARAMETERS>>
}'

I need to invoke vbscript in place of <<INVOKE VBSCRIPT WITH PARAMETERS>> Please help

Comment: @user646108 Please don't post code snippets in comments (unless they're 1-liners), because the code tends to become unreadable. Instead update your question with it.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include an example of calling from a .BAT file and calling from a .JS file. Hope this helps.

Comment: This was tested with a .VBS file being called from a .JS file. I have included my code lines from my two test files so that you can test it yourself.

Comment: I just added a .BAT example as well in case it comes up.

Comment: Hi @AxGryndr, How do I download the file from a secured url. I mean if the server asks for username password? Thanks in advance.